# Creating a semi-transparent 3D cube with borders in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, borders

I'm trying to create a 3D cube with different colored borders and face-transparency(while keeping the borders 100% opaque) in Illustrator. Like so(the dotted lines on the backside aren't completely necessary, but would be nice too):

[image: 3D cube with borders]

I've made the cube below using Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel, with "Draw hidden faces" checked, and making the fill semi-transparent:

[image: Semi-transparent cube]

I've tried fiddling with all of the color settings I can find for the original 2D square, but I'm having trouble getting a border to show and not extrude as well.

This is the cube with a border color defined on the 2D square & with the opacity of just the fill reduced:

[image: Cube attempt so far]

Anyone know how to do this **while keeping the cube/shape unexpanded, without hand-drawing each side, etc**, or if it's even possible in Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

With what you've already done just select the cube and then do Object → Expand Appearance and you can fine tune whatever you'd like.

---

Alternatively you could've just

1. Draw a square
2. Duplicate the square
3. Move the duplicate to your desired position
4. Use Pen Tool to draw in remaining walls from corner to corner
5. Adjust to taste

Comment: You should probably explicitly mention you ned to expand *before* applying the stroke. (seems obvious but maybe not to everyone)

Comment: @Cai you don't *need* to. Might save a few clicks but once expanded you can just change the colors or delete those pieces anyways.

Comment: I should have specified, but ideally I'm looking for a solution that keeps the cube in the 3D, un-expanded state. I've already resorted to manually drawing the cube as an alternative, but I was curious if the former was possible.